# Using Webpacker with jQuery without code duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I want to create a Rails 5 project without using a framework like React. But I want to use jQuery and I also want to use Yarn with jQuery to manage my dependencies.

The Webpacker documentation illustrates usage with a framework like React:

```
 rails new myapp --webpack=react

app/javascript:
  ├── packs:
  │ 
  │   └── application.js
  └── src:
  │   └── application.css
  └── images:
      └── logo.svg 

<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

./bin/webpack and ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

I found a documentation illustrating how to use it with jQuery and rails-ujs. But it uses both Webpacker and the Assets Pipeline, which makes no sense to me:

```
yarn add jquery
rails yarn:install
gem 'jquery-rails'
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
rails webpacker:install
```

'yarn add' will add jQuery to the Yarn global cache:

```
$ yarn cache list | grep jquery
jquery  3.4.0 npm https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jquery/-/jquery-3.4.0.tgz#8de513fa0fa4b2c7d2e48a530e26f0596936efdf
```

So why do we need to install jQuery again via Rails? It is extreme code duplication here. The point of using Yarn was to avoid managing the gems through Ruby directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that does not make sense.

`//= require jquery` does not work for webpackER.

`yarn add` will add a package to `node_modules`, you can see these listed in your `package.json` file.

Try to add the following packages with `yarn add`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ujs (notice the dash, NOT a `_`)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbolinks

Then, in `application.js` or another file under `/packs`:

```js
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ujs';
var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks");
Turbolinks.start(); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbolinks#installation-using-npm
```

This should get you to a point where all libs are running like they would on asset pipeline.